# What is the difference between "server_lifetime" and "server_idle_timeout"?

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I am trying to tweak my `pgbouncer.ini` file in Pgbouncer and came up with `server_lifetime` and `server_idle_timeout` parameters which I felt the same.

In the [official configuration document](http://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html) it says:

### server_lifetime

> The pooler will close an unused server connection that has been connected longer than this. Setting it to 0 means the connection is to be used only once, then closed. [seconds]
>
> Default: 3600.0

### server_idle_timeout

> If a server connection has been idle more than this many seconds it will be dropped. If 0 then timeout is disabled. [seconds]
>
> Default: 600.0

Could you help me understand the difference in simple terms? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pgbouncer will close any server connection that has been connected longer than `server_lifetime` whenever possible according to `pool_mode`.
Imagine a pool under constant load. Without `server_lifetime`, pgbouncer will open N server connections and use they for months. It's not so bad, but not always desirable. In some cases the database server processes will take more and more memory over time (cache of stored procedures, prepared statements, etc). `server_lifetime`  will close old server connections without the application being aware of it (new server connection will be established later, if needed). This will happen regardless of how active the connection was.

On the other hand, `server_idle_timeout` will close connections to the server that have not been used by clients during this time. Usecase: typically a few connections to the server are sufficient for this pool. But sometimes we have a peak of activity and we open 50 connections. When we processed this peak, these additional connections are no longer needed, we only need a few of them. `server_idle_timeout` allows you to close server connections that have not been used for longer than the specified time. `server_lifetime` will also close such unneeded connections, but a separate `server_idle_timeout` option will allow a shorter interval to be set.

---

> what Pgbouncer considers as `unused server connection` if it is different from an idle connection?

From pgbouncer's point of view, an unused connection is a connection that is not currently linked to any client connection. This is related to `pool_mode` as follows:

- in pool mode `statement`, the server connection is linked with the client (and is "used") only during the execution of the query.
- in pool mode `transaction`, the server connection is linked to some client while the transaction is in progress.
- in pool mode `session` the client connection is linked to the server connection until the client disconnects.

So, an `idle` connection in terms of postgresql view `pg_stat_activity` will be `unused` in pool mode `statement` or `transaction`. But unknown in pool mode `session` - pgbouncer can wait for further commands from the client (and therefore the server connection is `idle` for postgresql, but `used` for pgbouncer) or this connection is not currently assigned to anyone (`unused` for pgbouncer, but the same `idle` for postgresql)

Strictly speaking, server connections from pgbouncer can be in one of the following statuses:

- `active` - server connections that are linked to a client.
- `idle` - server connections that are unused and immediately usable for client queries.
- `used` - server connections that have been idle for more than server_check_delay, so they need server_check_query to run on them before they can be used again.
- `tested` - server connections that are currently running either server_reset_query or server_check_query.
- `login` - server connections currently in the process of logging in.

(not well documented, see [`SHOW POOLS` description](https://www.pgbouncer.org/usage.html#admin-console))

Connections in `used`, `tested` and `idle` statuses are inspected for `server_lifetime` [condition here](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/blob/pgbouncer_1_16_0/src/janitor.c#L454) and [called here](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/blob/pgbouncer_1_16_0/src/janitor.c#L509). [And here](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/blob/pgbouncer_1_16_0/src/objects.c#L778) is an additional check on transition from `active`/`used`/`tested` to `idle` status. Server connections in `used`, `tested` or `idle` status are subject to `server_lifetime` or `server_idle_timeout` timeouts. Thus, these timeouts do not affect clients.

Comment: Very clear on `server_idle_timeout` explanation.  For `server_lifetime`, I understand your point regarding clearing the Postgres server-side memory. In the documentation, it says `the pooler will close an unused connection` which is confusing. Could you explain it a little bit more? Further, can you add what Pgbouncer considers as `unused server connection` if it is different from an `idle connection`? Also, does `pool_mode` change the behavior of closing unused connections?

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation with all the references I need to understand your answer.  In my particular case, I am using `pool_mode` as `transaction`. Based on your explanation; for my scenario, `idle` in PostgreSQL's perspective will be `unused` in Pgbouncer's perspective. Therefore, whichever (out of `server_lifetime` and `server_idle_timeout`) has the least value will become the timeout to close the connection with the server. There is no point in having two different values for these two parameters if `pool_mode=transaction`. Am I correct?

Comment: `server_lifetime` and `server_idle_timeout` are counted from different time points. `server_lifetime` will close connection, counting not far from `pg_stat_activity.backend_start`; `server_idle_timeout` is counted from how long the connection has been idle (something near `pg_stat_activity.state_change` for `idle` connection). Therefore, I see no point to set both equals. The second will not actually be used. A connection cannot be unused for longer than its lifetime. Usually I have server_lifetime = few hours and server_idle_timeout = 10-30 min

Comment: Understood. Thanks again for the detailed explanation. Cheers 

Comment: Great answer. Just adding that [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) is a PostgreSQL view.